# alternative to nextElementSibling

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I currently have a code that when a div is click, it add a style to the next div using `nextElementSibling`.

```js
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    console.log(panel)
    if (panel.style.display === "block") {
      panel.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      panel.style.display = "block";
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<div class="accordion">
  <p>Resources</p>
</div>
<div class=panel ">
 Test message
</div>
```

This add a style to the div with the class `panel`. I need to move the class `accordion` to the `p` tag instead of the `div`

like this:

```html
<div>
  <p class="accordion">Resources</p> 
</div>
<div class= panel">
  Test message
</div>
```

How do I target panel now that's `accordion` is no longer next to `panel`?

Comment: Just try `this.parentNode.nextElementSibling`

Comment: you need child selectors instead. e. g. `this.children[0].classList.add('accordion')` and remove the class from the clicked element

Comment: also if you do 'queryselectorAll()' instead of getting a collection by class name. the resulting array won't be live and still iterable even if that element no longer contains that class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the `p` is now child of the `div` which is a sibling to `.panel`, you can use `parentElement` to get back to that level of the DOM before using `nextElementSibling`, like this:

```js
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.parentElement.nextElementSibling;
    
    if (panel.style.display === "block") {
      panel.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      panel.style.display = "block";
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.panel { display: none; }
.active { color: #C00; }
```

```html
<div><p class="accordion">Resources</p></div>
<div class="panel">Test message</div>

<div><p class="accordion">Resources</p></div>
<div class="panel">Test message</div>

<div><p class="accordion">Resources</p></div>
<div class="panel">Test message</div>
```

Also note that if you don't need to support IE you can use more modern methods to achieve the same JS logic more succinctly:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.accordion').forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener('click', e => {
    let accordion = e.target;
    accordion.classList.toggle('active');
    accordion.parentElement.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle('show');
  });
});
```

```css
.panel { display: none; }
.panel.show { display: block; }
.active { color: #C00; }
```

```html
<div><p class="accordion">Resources</p></div>
<div class="panel">Test message</div>

<div><p class="accordion">Resources</p></div>
<div class="panel">Test message</div>

<div><p class="accordion">Resources</p></div>
<div class="panel">Test message</div>
```

Comment: how do I automatically close one when I open another?